# c++ local function within a namespace

Tags: c++, function, namespaces, nested, local

Coming from ADA there is one thing I really miss in C++ and that is the ability to use nested or local functions. In ADA I could do this for example:

```
procedure TotalSum ()
is
    function Sum (a : Float; b : Float) return Float;
    is
    begin
        return a + b;
    end Sum;

    x : Float := 1.0;
    y : Float := 1.0;
    z : Float := 1.0;
    sum : Float;
begin
    sum := Sum(x,y);
    sum := Sum(sum,z);
end TotalSum;
```

The advantage of this is that I can limit the scope of functions that are only used locally. For classes I got used to the fact that I can declare a function private in order to limit the scope (which limits the scope to some extend). But now I'm implementing a function library in a namespace instead of a class and I've not been able to find a nice solution to limit the scope of my local functions.

Is there a best practice to accomplish the above in a C++ namespace.

Comment: I am not really sure what you re trying to achieve. But if all you want is to limit the scope of these functions in c++ just add them into a namespace ( e.g: sumname ) and use them: `sumname::TotalSum()` and `sumname::Sum()`

Comment: What's wrong with anonymous namespaces? They limit the scope of your local functions to a single translation unit.

Comment: @DimChtz: What I want to accomplish is that my function Sum() in this example is not known to the users of my library. In this example it might not really make sense, but in my real code I often implement helper functions that I don't want the users of my library to use directly (for instance to prevent wrong use).

Comment: In that case, you should really go with lambda functions as @Cristophe answered

Comment: @Algirdas: Anonymous namespaces might just be what I'm looking for 'm going to look into that...

Lambda function is not an option, since I  have to use an older version of C++.

Answer (score 7):

You can perfectly define local functions using **lambda functions**:

```
int TotalSum () {

    auto Sum = [](float a, float b) -> float {
        return a + b;
    };

    float x= 1.0;
    float y= 1.0;
    float z= 1.0;

    float sum = Sum(x,y);
    sum = Sum(sum,z);
    return sum; 
}
```

Another approach to keep a function completely local to an implementation could be to use **anonymous namespace**.  The elements defined in an anonymous namespace are local to the translation unit (i.e. in one cpp file only):

```
namespace mylib {

    namespace {   // nested anonymous namespace - visible only in this cpp 
        float Sum (float a, float b) {
            return a + b;
        }
    };

    int TotalSum () {
        ... 
    }

}
```